# malloc error when computing descriptor OpenCV

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, feature-descriptor

I'm working with OpenCV to compute ORB descriptors, the problem I'm having is that at random points in the execution I get an error like this

> LightFieldRecovery(3468,0x7fff73a9a310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100911608: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I am not working with any pointer (explicitly) I am using std::vectors as data containers.
The code is too long to post it here but you could see it https://github.com/BRabbit27/LigthField/blob/master/LightFieldRecovery/main.cpp

Does any one can spot where could this error be? I've been looking for it the whole day.

I'm working under OS X Mavericks, Xcode 5 and C++ (under Build Settings in Xcode the *C++ Language Dialect* is set to *-std=gnu++11* otherwise I cannot compile OpenCV code)

**EDIT**

With help of Valgrind I was able to narrow the problem to the following pieces of code, but I don't see what the error is, I don't understand what am I missing when copying data from a `cv::Mat` into an `uchar*` pointer.

**Error A**

```
        //GET THE RIGHT AND DOWN NEIGHBORS TO COMPUTE THE DIFFERENCES
        uint offset = 0;
        for (Pixel p : patchPos)
        {
            uint r = p.getY();
            uint c = p.getX();

            uchar pixelV = ((uchar*)camRef->getData())[r*imageW+c];

            uint cRightNeighbor = c+patchStep;
            uchar pixelVrightP = 0;

            if (cRightNeighbor < imageW)
            {
                pixelVrightP = abs(pixelV - ((uchar*)camRef->getData())[r*imageW+cRightNeighbor]);
            }

            uint rDownNeighbor = r+patchStep;
            uchar pixelVbelowP = 0;

            if (rDownNeighbor < imageH)
            {
                pixelVbelowP = abs(pixelV - ((uchar*)camRef->getData())[rDownNeighbor*imageW+c]);
            }

            //THIS IS PART OF THE ERROR
            Cdiff[iPatch*(patchSize*patchSize)*2 + offset] = pixelVrightP;
            Cdiff[iPatch*(patchSize*patchSize)*2 + offset+(patchSize*patchSize)] = pixelVbelowP;
            offset++;
        }
```

**Error B**

Apparently the way I am pretending to use `memset` is not a good one.

```
            for (uint dRow = 0; dRow < camPatchKeyPoints.size(); dRow++)
            {
                if (camPatchKeyPoints[dRow].pt.x < 0   || camPatchKeyPoints[dRow].pt.y < 0 ||
                    camPatchKeyPoints[dRow].pt.x > imageW || camPatchKeyPoints[dRow].pt.y > imageH)
                {
                    memset(&(d.data[dRow*d.cols]), 0, sizeof(uchar)*d.cols);
                }
            }
```

**Error C**

Similarly with `memcpy` I'm passing the wrong params or copying into an out of bounds region

```
        dst = Q;
        for (uint dl = 0; dl < disparityLevels; dl++)
        {
            for (uint c = 0; c < (nTotalCams-1); c++)
            {
                memcpy(dst, &(((uchar*)(camsDescriptors[c].data))[dl*DESCRIPTOR_SIZE]), sizeof(uchar)*DESCRIPTOR_SIZE);
                dst += DESCRIPTOR_SIZE;
            }
        }
```

**Error D**

```
    dst = Y;
    for (cv::Mat refD : refsDescriptors)
    {
        memcpy(dst, refD.data, sizeof(uchar)*DESCRIPTOR_SIZE);
        dst += DESCRIPTOR_SIZE;
    }
```

Comment: On the contrary, you're working with *many* pointers (explicitly). *And* you're using `strcat` with an uninitialized buffer. Why don't you use `std::string` everywhere?

Comment: What I meant was that the `std::vector`s I'm using does not contain pointers. I'll check the `strcat`, I don't know why I didn't use `std::string`.

Comment: I don't know if using `std::string` had an actual impact on the code, but now it runs a little bit more than it did, but still randomly crashes sending the same message. Any idea on where/how to track this bug?

Comment: One thing i'd change straight away is `char *sd = new char[250]; strcat(sd, imageFolder);`. Not going into why this is a bad idea in the first place (we have `std::string` for a reason), you're allocating memory but that first `strcat` should be a `strcpy`. As-written `strcat` is walking over indeterminate memory content, looking for a nullchar to identify where to begin concatenating data. Lord only knows where it eventually finds one.

Comment: I should also note that, without seeing the constructor for `Camera`, I'm going to assume it isn't designed to "take ownership" of the `imagePath` construction parameter (a `char *), and as such you're leaking memory as well.

Comment: Nope, it does not take ownership of a `char*` parameter. I create the image and then only pass the imageData to the camera where I copy the info where the destructor of the camera is in charge of freeing that memory.

Comment: Any idea on what to do to track down the bug? Or any other idea that makes the code less complex and less prone to errors?